# libinput can't detect the touchpad

Tags: linux, arch-linux, touchpad

libinput can't detect touchpad while I can use the touchpad in BIOS

```
sudo libinput list-devices | grep Device

Device:           Power Button
Device:           Asus Wireless Radio Control
Device:           Video Bus
Device:           Lid Switch
Device:           Video Bus
Device:           Power Button
Device:           Sleep Button
Device:           KYE SYSTEMS CORP. Wired Mouse
Device:           USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 HD
Device:           HDA Intel PCH Mic
Device:           HDA Intel PCH Headphone
Device:           HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3
Device:           HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7
Device:           HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8
Device:           HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9
Device:           HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10
Device:           Asus WMI hotkeys
Device:           AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to boot using a bootable usb flash drive and see if your touchpad is working there.

If touchpad works there and you're sure this isn't a hardware problem try to boot using another kernel in grub. If this goes correct you have to reinstall your latest kernel or maybe wait this is a kernel bug and you should wait for an update. Either way you should update your grub afterwards, although almost all Linux OSs do this automatically after installing a new kernel.

If another kernel doesn't work too, add these to your grub line which starts with linux or linuxefi (based upon if you boot your linux in legacy mode or UEFI mode).

**1) `selinux=0`**

This boots your linux up with selinux disabled, although it's very odd you messed your touchpad drivers' selinux properties, but it's worth a shot.

**2) `pci=nommconf`**

This one disables a mechanism which caches pci connections in memory and sometimes it causes problems, this is very odd too but you can try this.

**3) `nouveau.modeset=0` OR `nomodeset`**

This one disables nouveau driver which is a open-source driver for nvidia gpus, I've seen this causing problems in many laptops specially the ones who have Intel GPUs too. 
Disabling this will boot your system either with Intel GPU or if you had nvidia driver installed with your nvidia driver.

Last but not least remove `rhgb quiet` from your grub line to see how your linux is booting up and maybe for errors.

Comment: Actually, I downgrade the kernel from 4.19.36-1-lts to 4.19.34-1-lts and it works! i